# Django query with ManyToMany relationship through

Tags: python, django

I am implementing the connect function like Linkedin.
My models are

```
class AFSUser(models.Model):
    connects = models.ManyToManyField("self", through='UserConnect', symmetrical=False)

class UserConnect(models.Model):
    date_followed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_approved = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_rejected = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(AFSUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='request_user')
    acceptor = models.ForeignKey(AFSUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='accept_user')
```

I want to list connections of a user.
I tried

```
approved_connections = UserConnect.objects.filter(Q(requester=afsUser) | Q(acceptor=afsUser),                                                  date_aprroved__isnull=False,
                                                                  date_rejected__isnull=False)
```

Then get the list from there.
Any other way so i can do

```
users = userA.connects.filter(...)
```

Comment: What you want to obtain is not very clear. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `through`

```
userA.connects.through.objects.filter(Q(requester= userA)|Q(acceptor=userA))
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for.